# CloudSQL Postgres confused around table grants and owners

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, postgresql-11

I'm using CloudSQL Postgres 11 on GCP, and I've got a few questions around permissions and grants. I'm just not getting it at the moment, being very new to postgres.

I have a user, `pgadmin` which is a superuser. With this user I can connect to the instance and create a database called 'sandbox' for example.

I then have an app role which is defined as follows:

```
CREATE ROLE app;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE <database name> TO app;
GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO app;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO app;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO app;
GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO app;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO app;
```

I create a user called app_sandbox which I grant this role.

The app user then makes a db migration using flyway which creates 2 tables. That side of things is fine.

But with my superuser, pgadmin, I can't see these tables or query them even though this user owns the database and is a superuser. I've tried all sorts of grants. Feels like I'm missing something important because even if I true to create a readonly role with the pgadmin user I am unable to grant access to the underlying tables in the public schema of the database.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Just because one user (=`pgadmin`) owns the database, does not mean that user also owns the tables created in that database. And because `pgadmin` doesn't own those tables, you can't access them when logged in as `pgadmin`

If the app user created the tables, they belong to that user, and only the `app` user can grant privileges on those tables to other users.